# New Relic/Varnish integration - how to show second instance?

Tags: plugins, varnish, newrelic

I have succesfully install the plugins to show Varnish statuses on New Relic, following this guide here:

https://github.com/varnish/newrelic_varnish_plugin

The problem is, when I install it to my second web server (using the same API key), nothing new show up in New Relic but the varnish[default] instance.

Does anyone know how to setup a second instance in this case?

Thanks alot.

Hiep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved according to this comment: https://github.com/varnish/newrelic_varnish_plugin/issues/13#issuecomment-26779670.

Basically we need to change the `"default"` string in following line to something unique:

```
agent_human_labels("Varnish") { "#{@name||"varnish"}[#{@vname||"default"}]"}
```

Hope it will be patched soon to allow using other variable than vname.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the name for the second instance?

https://github.com/varnish/newrelic_varnish_plugin/blob/master/config/template_newrelic_plugin.yml#L36

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will try to change it. Will update the result later.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. After turn on second instance, it **overwrites** data of first instance. It show very clear in [this graph](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0281vhym7b). Do you think it's a bug?